# Scaning the smaller text from Camera Android

Tags: android, ocr

I need to scan the smaller text from Camera in Android using this https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr Project. This project is working for bigger text.I need to scan Bills(bills like current bills, etc...) with Text font size is 8 to 10sp.Please help me ASAP.Thanks is Advance.

I need to scan the below Image.Check out the sample Image.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeEqY.jpg)

Comment: have u tried anything?

Comment: yes but not scanning the correct text.

Comment: what's the actual question? You're saying that you have to use Android OCR and that it's not working for you for smaller text but are you asking for other libraries or where do you need input?

Comment: @Patrik, Using the same library I need to scan smaller text.

Comment: The print size of the text doesn't matter much as long as the print quality is good enough. What you need is enough resolution in your picture and for that you might need to go closer with your camera. Android OCR might be quite sensitive to image degradation and accuracy might suffer when the image is out of focus. If you need to be able to extract information even when the text is blurred, other techniques (neural networks?) might perform better.

Comment: Thanks for the response Patrik, can I zoom the Camera with focus using this project?can you please list me set of libraries with OCR.

Comment: Could you please show a sample  image of the Bill?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I have edited the question, Please check the Image @ssasa